# Bottle web framework: how to return a csv file to angular client

Tags: python, bottle

In bottle web framework i need to return a csv file to download from a angular client.

```
@route('/project/download')
def download_projects_result_file():
    #here i have a csv file in /tmp/proj_category.csv

    return ....?
```

How can i return a csv file to client?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to load the file's contents in the client or download directly?

To download directly, use `Content-Disposition` header in the bottle response.

Here's an example:

```
from bottle import LocalResponse, route

@route('/project/download')
def download_projects_result_file():
    with open('/tmp/proj_category.csv') as file:
        file.seek(0)
        byte_data = file.read()
        response = LocalResponse(
            body=byte_data,
            headers={
                "Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename='filename.csv'",
                "Content-Type": "text/csv",
            }
        )
        return response
```

Comment: and to download file's content in the client using blob?

Comment: You want to simply load the file's contents into the client? Or something more?